# How to match values in different tables in SQLite?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to create a database function that will help me match my student id. table_userinfo has already student id, name and course values stored in it. table_users is empty which accept email, student id and password from user. I want to create a function where only the student id stored in table_userinfo can register, otherwise show an error that student doesn't exists. The student id inputted by the user should also retrieve the corresponding course and name from table_userinfo. Also is my code for inserting values right or not. Because i tried it before and i got a run error in the first insert value line.

```
//Code for table creation
 public static final String SQL_TABLE_USERS = " CREATE TABLE " +    
TABLE_USERS
         + " ( "
         + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
         + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
         + KEY_SID + " INTEGER, "
         + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT"
         + " ) ";

 //SQL for creating user info table
 public static final String SQL_TABLE_USERINFO = " CREATE TABLE "    
+ TABLE_USERINFO
         + " ( "
         + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
         + KEY_SID + " INTEGER, "
         + KEY_NAME + "TEXT, "
         + KEY_COURSE + " TEXT "
         + " ) ";


 public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
     //Create Table when oncreate gets called
     sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABLE_USERS);
     sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABLE_USERINFO);
     sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE_USERINFO 
   VALUES('01','45207160010','Mary James','TYBSCIT')");
     sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE_USERINFO 
  VALUES('02','45207160020','Amelia John','FYBCOM')");
```

UPDATE:-
I have now two functions for checking if email exists and if student exists in my sqlite code. But when i call the functions from the register page, the app crashes and the log says that the error is at the function when the register button is clicked. I am sharing the code of my functions and registration page. Please tell me if i am making some mistake. I have already tried different combinations of for loops o my registration page. Doesn't work. However if put only the Email exists function, it works then.

SQLITE code

```
 public boolean ifUserInCourse(String sid) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = KEY_SID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{sid};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_USERINFO,null, whereclause, whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) rv = true;
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }


    public boolean isEmailExists(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS,// Selecting Table
                new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_SID, KEY_PASSWORD},//Selecting columns want to query
                KEY_EMAIL + "=?",
                new String[]{email},//Where clause
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()&& cursor.getCount()>0) {
            //if cursor has value then in user database there is user associated with this given email so return true
            return true;
        }

        //if email does not exist return false
        return false;
    }
```

Registration code

```
buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validate()) {
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String SID = editTextSID.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //Check in the database is there any user associated with  this email

                        if (!sqliteHelper.ifUserInCourse(SID) && !sqliteHelper.isEmailExists(Email)) {

                            sqliteHelper.addUser(new User(null, Email, SID, Password));
                            Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User created successfully! Please Login ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);


                        } else {
                            if(sqliteHelper.isEmailExists(Email)) {

                                Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "Email already exists ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            } else {

                                Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User doesn't exists ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: JOIN the tables ON one or more fields, eventually specifying some matching criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue 1 as per :-

> Also is my code for inserting values right or not. Because i tried it
>   before and i got a run error in the first insert value line.

Unless you have `public static final String TABLE_USERINFO = "TABLE_USERINFO";` which considering the near duplicate of the is question, you don't then

```
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE_USERINFO VALUES('01','45207160010','Mary James','TYBSCIT')");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE_USERINFO VALUES('02','45207160020','Amelia John','FYBCOM')");
```

Will result in an exception due to table not found.

I believe that you instead should be using :-

```
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USERINFO + " VALUES('01','45207160010','Mary James','TYBSCIT')");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USERINFO + " VALUES('02','45207160020','Amelia John','FYBCOM')");
```

- i.e. user the variable TABLE_USERINFO rather than the hard coded value TABLE_USERINFO.

Additionally you will encounter issues as you have `+ KEY_NAME + "TEXT, "` instead of `+ KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "` (space omitted).

## Issue 2 as per :-

> I want to create a function where only the student id stored in
>   table_userinfo can register, otherwise show an error that student
>   doesn't exists. The student id inputted by the user should also
>   retrieve the corresponding course and name from table_userinfo.

The following **SqliteHelper.java** would facilitate the above (*taking into consideration your response to the answer provided previously for a similar question*)

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "user_reg";
    public static final String TABLE_USERINFO = "user_info";

    public static final String KEY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_SID = "sid";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_COURSE = "coures";



    public static final String SQL_TABLE_USERS = " CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_USERS
            + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_SID + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT"
            + " ) ";

    //SQL for creating user info table
    public static final String SQL_TABLE_USERINFO = " CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_USERINFO
            + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_SID + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_COURSE + " TEXT "
            + " ) ";

    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        //Create Table when oncreate gets called
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABLE_USERS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABLE_USERINFO);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USERINFO + " VALUES('01','45207160010','Mary James','TYBSCIT')");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_USERINFO + " VALUES('02','45207160020','Amelia John','FYBCOM')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long registerUser(String sid, String email, String password) {
        if (email.length() < 1) return -9999;
        if (password.length() < 1) return -9998;
        if (sid.length() < 1) return -9997;
        if (ifUserRegistered(sid)) return -99; // Check if user is already registered
        if (!ifUserInCourse(sid)) return  -999;  // Check if user is enrolled in a course perhpas optional
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_SID,sid);
        cv.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
        cv.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.insert(TABLE_USERS,null,cv);
    }

    public boolean ifUserRegistered(String sid) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = KEY_SID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{sid};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_USERS,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) rv = true;
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public boolean ifUserInCourse(String sid) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = KEY_SID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{sid};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_USERINFO,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) rv = true;
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromSID(String sid) {
        String rv = "";
        String whereclause = KEY_SID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{sid};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_USERINFO,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public String getUserCourseFromSID(String sid) {
        String rv = "";
        String whereclause = KEY_SID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{sid};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_USERINFO,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_COURSE));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

## Testing

The above was tested using the following code in an activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SqliteHelper mSQLHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSQLHlpr = new SqliteHelper(this);
        long result1 = mSQLHlpr.registerUser("010101010101010101","blah@mail.com","1234567890");
        long result2 = mSQLHlpr.registerUser("45207160010","xxxx@mail.com","1234567890");
        long result3 = mSQLHlpr.registerUser("45207160010","yyyy@mail.com","1234567890");


        Log.d(
                "RESULTS",
                "\tFirst attempt returned " + String.valueOf(result1) + " " + String.valueOf((result1 > 0)) +
                        "\n\tSecond attempt returned " + String.valueOf(result2) + " " + String.valueOf(result2 > 0) +
                        "\n\tThird attempt returned " + String.valueOf(result3) + " " + String.valueOf(result3 > 0)
        );

        String testsid = "45207160010";

        Log.d(
                "USERBYSID",
                "SID " + testsid + " " +
                        "Has a name of " + mSQLHlpr.getUserNameFromSID(testsid) +
                        " and a Course of " + mSQLHlpr.getUserNameFromSID(testsid)
        );
    }
}
```

- **Note** the above was used for testing purposes it is not intended for an actual App as the results would then perhaps be confusing due to rows already existing.

## Result

The above produced the following relevant output :-

```
2019-02-05 12:38:08.684 21533-21533/? D/RESULTS:    First attempt returned -999 false
        Second attempt returned 1 true
        Third attempt returned -99 false
2019-02-05 12:38:08.686 21533-21533/? D/USERBYSID: SID 45207160010 Has a name of Mary James and a Course of Mary James
```

- -999 is the code for the SID not existing
- 1 being positive indicates that the row was successfully inserted and therefore that all tests were passed.
- -99 is the code for the SID already having been registered.

Comment: I actually tried it already adding a function to check the sid in the second table. But i got an error before too and now i tried again, i get an error. I don't know what it is but on clicking the registration button and passing the values some error comes in the sqlite function line to check for sid. I tried using different loops but can't seem to find out the problem.